# Why does a list of Iconize objects not work with Map

Tags: list-manipulation, map, iconize

I am trying to understand how to Map a function onto a list of Iconize objects. Here is a simple example:

```
listOfIconize = Table[ Iconize[Range[10 + i]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

This creates what you would expect. If you cut and paste one element of the list into the following expression in order to sum the list that's iconized then it works as you would expect:

```
Apply[Plus,<copied iconize>]
```

Now try and evaluate this expression:

```
Map[Apply[Plus, #] &, listOfIconize]
```

You will then get a list with Automatic and Method -> Automatic statements.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the 'Possible Issues' section of [`Iconize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html).

```
Map[Apply[Plus, First@#] &, listOfIconize]
```